# Location of Google Logo on Map in iOS Application

Tags: ios, google-maps

Is there an approval process that I must follow in order to move the "Google" that is in the left-hand corner to another area of the map?  I have an application where my UI will cover these words and would like to display them in another location on the Google map. I know how to do this in iOS, just don't know if there are legal concerns with Google in doing so.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't.. That violates a [Google Maps term](http://www.google.com/help/terms_maps.html):

> (f) delete, obscure, or in any manner alter any warning, notice
>   (including but not limited to any copyright or other proprietary
>   rights notice), or link that appears in the Products or the Content;

and the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

> 8.6 Google Maps and Google Earth images obtained via the Google Maps API can be used within an application if all brand features of the original content remain unaltered and fully visible. Apps that cover up or modify the Google logo or copyright holders identification will be rejected

Comment: Adjusting the location of the branding is not altering the branding itself. And the OP clearly states that the purpose for moving it is specifically to prevent it from being obscured. I think mwielbut's response should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: I think @taraloca dont want to hide the logo but to make it visible by giving some padding.

Comment: How to show the copyright information in google map in iPhones. It shows up in iPads ??

Answer (score 27):

Google Maps now provides the ability to modify the outer padding of the map, specifically for the purpose of allowing the developer to move map controllers, recenter the map, and un-obscure legal and copyright information that may otherwise be covered by other user designed UI elements.

Example:

```
// Insets are specified in this order: top, left, bottom, right
UIEdgeInsets mapInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 300.0);
GMSMapView *mapView_;
mapView_.padding = mapInsets;
```

Legal:

> Note: As per the Google Maps API terms of service, your application must not remove or obscure the Google logo or copyright notices. Map Padding allows you to reposition these elements if necessary. **If you display a custom UI at the bottom of the map, add padding to the bottom of the map so that the logo and legal notices will always be visible.**

Google docs:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/map#map_padding

*I'm not certain if this will still violate Apple's legal terms but Google is clearly OK with moving the logo as long as it's still at the bottom left and not obscured.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by buying google api business license https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/
and this will not violate google terms or App store review Guidelines