# how to position myLocationButton google maps IOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

Currently, myLocationButton is buried behind a button, if you take a look at the button the myLocationButton is behind that button. How do I move the Y position of the myLocationButton?

[image]

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885596/location-of-google-logo-on-map-in-ios-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GMSMapView`'s `padding` to make this happen.

```
self.mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 100, 0)
```

Replace `'100'` with whatever space you want the location-button to be pushed up. You should probably replace it with the `y-location` of your book-button. For example:

```
let botPadding = self.view.frame.size.height - self.bookButton.frame.origin.y
self.mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, botPadding, 0)
```

You can probably put this code wherever you want, maybe it'll work in `viewDidLoad`. But keep in mind that you'll have to call it again if your book-button is supposed to disappear at some point.
To make it dynamically placed, you could override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or similar.

Comment: So which solution should I use, override the subViews? or use mapView.padding?

Comment: and One more thing, how do i get paddingBelowBookButton?

Comment: Thanks I tried your solution and it works, for paddingBelowBookButton I just add 10